# modelformset_factory excludes too many fields

Tags: django, formset

I think it may be a bug in modelformset_factory in Django 1.2, but I'd like anyone else to double check that (possibly in newer djnago versions as well).

Just for courious people - models are representing possible scores, and sets of those available for worker's training reports.

models.py:

```
class ScoreSet(Model):
    unit = ForeignKey(Unit)
    description = CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='description')

class Score(Model):
    scoreset = ForeignKey(ScoreSet)
    score = CharField(max_length=8, verbose_name='score')
    description = CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='description')
```

and now:

```
FormSet = modelformset_factory(Score, exclude='scoreset', extra=5, can_delete=True)
```

will produce formset with no scoreset **and no score** field. If you change "scoreset" field name to anything else (eg. "ss") it works fine, and excludes only "ss" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude should be a tuple, not a string:

```
exclude=('scoreset',)
```

Comment: You're right. Thanks. Anyway it's strange behavior, that exclude='scoreset' works, and excludes both 'score' and 'scoreset', while exclude='ss' excludes only 'ss'.

Comment: If you use the wrong types in Python, you can get unexpected behaviour. In this case, note that `score in 'scoreset'` evaluates to True, but `score in 'ss'` doesn't.